# Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to send an image using a share button

I have an image in the UIViewcontroller called self.image

```
func share(_ sender: Any) {
    let imageToShare = self.image?
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However I got the following error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type '[Any]'
```

Could it be that this has something to do with the optional value type of self.image?
How do I make it non-optional while the function doesnt crash when someone click the button?

Comment: activityItems takes an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activityItems` is expecting to get an Array. So you could make `imageToShare` non optional and send it as an Array (that contains only this image).

1. Make it non-optional using `if let`
2. Make an Array that contains this image using `[imageToShare]`

The complete solution would be:

```
if let imageToShare = self.image? {
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            // present the view controller
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to comprehend the error that says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type
>   '[Any]'

It literally says the type (optional or not!) is not the expected `[Any]` type.  Since a `UIImage` can be `Any`, how about you try `let imageToShare = [self.image]`?

In that case, you have `[Any?]` type. An `Any?` object in an `Array`. Now if it still complains about the optional thing (it probably will), which you already know, then unwrap that object safely in any way you want, to make it `[Any]`.

Comment: i totally ignored the square brackets. Thanks